# Cannot Run VB.net Applications Simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, project, publish, simultaneous

I have two versions of the same VB.net project with different configurations (Different Connection string, settings...).
Lets call them `a` and `b`

I published both versions locally in seperate folder (for testing) however I cannot run `a` and `b` simultaneously.
If I run `a`, and try to run `b` nothing happens.
If I close `a` and run `b`, `b` opens successfully but now I am unable to run `b`.

I looked into this and noticed that both Applications had the same assembly name. After changing the assembly name to different values for each version, I was able to run both `a` and `b` simultaneously.

I am rather new to Visual Basics,
I have looked online for a more detailed explanation on why this is the case however I could not find a clear explanation.

Why am I unable to run the the different versions simultaneously? A more detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like SingleInstance set to true

Comment: It is, I tried setting it to false and publishing however when I ran `a` and subsequently ran `b` then it opened 2 instances of `a` rather than one of `a` and one of `b`

Comment: When you say "publish" are you actually talking about ClickOnce deployment or just basically building an EXE and copying it somewhere? Are you using different version numbers for the two apps?

Comment: yes, I am talking about ClickOnce deployment and yes I am using a different version number for the two apps.